# Magento2 - How to return string as object in webapi response?

Tags: magento2, rest-api, exception, object, response

Can anyone let me know how to return success message with object like this same as magento does for the exception in REST webapi:

```
{
    "message": "A customer with the same email already exists in an associated website."
}
```

Above is the example of exception message, same i want to do with success response, i tried with array but it returns an array with an object like this:

```
[
    {
        "message": "this is test"
    }
]
```

I don't want array but only object returns inside it.I have used following code for it:

```
$msg[] = array("message"=>"this is test");
return $msg;
```

Comment: @return string[] 

pass this in Interface function

Comment: I have used  @return string[] in interface but it still returns object with array, i only needs object like this:
 {
        "message": "test msg"
 }
not
[
    {
        "message": "test msg"
    }
]

Comment: @Amit, did you check?